# ASP.NET Web API request does not reach controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, large-files

I have trouble posting 'large' objects to my web api using the HttpClient's `PostAsJsonAsync` method. The objects contain a base64 encoded image file.

After a period which seems like the client's timeout setting, the exception

> 'A task was canceled.'

is thrown by the `HttpClient`. The timeout is already set very high (10 minutes). This only happens with files larger than ~2 MB. Anything smaller works fine. I know that the request does not even hit the first line of code in the controller method because the first line is a logging line and the log is empty. There are no exceptions in the server event viewer.

It is hard to pin down the issue because the controller works fine when I deploy the web api on my local IIS. But when I deploy it on my Azure VM, it only work for small files. The web.config files are identical.

`maxRequestLength` is already set high enough.

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
```

Instead of IIS hosting in an Azure VM, i've just tried to deploy the API as an app service. The exact same thing happens there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try setting this limit:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
       </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Note that contrary to the `maxRequestLength` parameter, this value is in bytes.

Comment: Could there be a load balancer in front of your web server that has such limitation? Because as far as ASP.NET is concerned, this should work.

Comment: I have no idea. It is an Azure VM with endpoints on tcp ports 80 and 443.
I'll file a support ticket at Microsoft.